# How to work with attributes in a main method of a multiclass package?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, arraylist, constructor

I'm a newbie. I'm writing a program that uses the following information to calculate grade for a number of students but I'm stuck from the beginning. I'm working with different classes in a package and I just don't know how to put them together in the main method. I received this message "non-static variable FirstName cannot be referenced from a static context Error." when I wrote " FirstName = oScan.nextLine();" at the last couple lines. My question is how to work with those attributes below in my main method 
First Name
Last Name
Homework Ave
Quiz Ave
Project Ave
Test Ave
Final Grade
Letter Grade

and did I write the right constructors, getters and setters?

/*
This is the first class, the parent class
 */

```
package student;

public class Person {



 protected String FirstName, LastName;

    //Constructor
    public Person(String FirstName, String LastName) {
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
    }

    //Getters
 public String getFirstName() {
        return FirstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return LastName;
    }
    //Setters
    public void setFirstName(String FirstName) {
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
    }

     public void setLastName(String LastName) {
        this.LastName = LastName;
    }


}
```

This is the second class

```
package student;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Student extends Person{
    private int HomeworkAve, QuizAve, ProjectAve, TestAve; 
    private double FinalGrade;
    private String LetterGrade;

//Constructor for the averages
    public Student(int HomeworkAve, int QuizAve, int ProjectAve, int TestAve, String FirstName, String LastName) 
    {
        super(FirstName, LastName);
        this.HomeworkAve = HomeworkAve;
        this.QuizAve = QuizAve;
        this.ProjectAve = ProjectAve;
        this.TestAve = TestAve;

    }

    //Method to calculate final grade and letter grade
    //Final grade calculation
    public double CalcGrade (int HomeworkAve, int QuizAve, int ProjectAve, int TestAve)
    {
FinalGrade = (double)(0.15*HomeworkAve + 0.05*QuizAve + 0.4 * ProjectAve + 0.4*TestAve);
return FinalGrade;
    }

    //Letter grade calculation
    public String CalcGrade ( double FinalGrade)
    {
        if ( FinalGrade >= 90.00)
        LetterGrade="A";
    else if(FinalGrade >= 80.00)
        LetterGrade="B";
    else if(FinalGrade>=70.00)
        LetterGrade="C";
    else if(FinalGrade>=60.00)
        LetterGrade="D";
    else LetterGrade="F";

        return LetterGrade;
    }



    public Student(int HomeworkAve, int QuizAve, int ProjectAve, int TestAve, double FinalGrade, String LetterGrade, String FirstName, String LastName) {
        super(FirstName, LastName);
        this.HomeworkAve = HomeworkAve;
        this.QuizAve = QuizAve;
        this.ProjectAve = ProjectAve;
        this.TestAve = TestAve;
        this.FinalGrade = FinalGrade;
        this.LetterGrade = LetterGrade;
    }


    //Setters for this student class
    public void setHomeworkAve(int HomeworkAve) {
        this.HomeworkAve = HomeworkAve;
    }

    public void setQuizAve(int QuizAve) {
        this.QuizAve = QuizAve;
    }

    public void setProjectAve(int ProjectAve) {
        this.ProjectAve = ProjectAve;
    }

    public void setTestAve(int TestAve) {
        this.TestAve = TestAve;
    }

    public void setFinalGrade(int FinalGrade) {
        this.FinalGrade = FinalGrade;
    }

    public void setLetterGrade(String LetterGrade) {
        this.LetterGrade = LetterGrade;
    }


    //Getters for this student class
    public int getHomeworkAve() {
        return HomeworkAve;
    }

    public int getQuizAve() {
        return QuizAve;
    }

    public int getProjectAve() {
        return ProjectAve;
    }

    public int getTestAve() {
        return TestAve;
    }

    public double getFinalGrade() {
        return FinalGrade;
    }

    public String getLetterGrade() {
        return LetterGrade;
    }


   public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner oScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner iScan = new Scanner(System.in);

   ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();



   System.out.println("Enter the number of students");

   int numberOfStudents = iScan.nextInt();

    for(int iCount = 0;iCount < numberOfStudents;){

    System.out.println("Enter the name for Student " + ++iCount);
    System.out.println("Enter First Name");
    String FirstName = oScan.nextLine();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Enter Last Name");
    String LastName = oScan.nextLine();
     System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Enter Homework Average");
    int HomeworkAve = iScan.nextInt();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Enter Quiz Average");
    int QuizAve = iScan.nextInt();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Enter Project Average");
    int ProjectAve = iScan.nextInt();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Enter Test Average");
    int TestAve = iScan.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    double Fin;



 Student hobbit = new Student(HomeworkAve,QuizAve, ProjectAve,TestAve,FirstName, LastName);
    students.add(hobbit);
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make an instance of the class in order to access non-static methods/variables.

That means this:

```
Person p = new Person("First Name Here", "Last Name");
```

Which is inefficient, so what you should do is,

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
   Scanner oScan = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter the number of students");

   int numberOfStudents = oScan.nextInt();

    for(int i = 0;i < numberOfStudents;i++){
    System.out.println("Enter First Name");
   String fn = oScan.nextLine();
    System.out.println(fn);

    System.out.println("Enter Last Name");
    String ln = oScan.nextLine();
    System.out.println(ln);

   //Add all the score stuff
 Student s = new Student(homeworkAve,quizAve,projectAve, testAve,fn,ln);
    students.add(s);
  }
}
```

EDIT: Edited to include a list

EDIT2: Edited to make "Student" objects

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. It helps but the user will determine the number of students through prompt by the program and then the students will be stored in an array of student objects. I just think an array will require a different solution.

Comment: No, it wont, let me edit the solution

Comment: Thanks again. This shed light into my progress. I just have another question, what do I need to do when I need to get input for the averages? cos the person class doesn't have these

Comment: I just have another question, what do I need to do when I need to get inputs for the averages? cos the person class doesn't have these

Comment: Use a simular setup, and make a student arraylist. You might want to change your constructor for students to read "Person p " instead of "String firstname, String lastname" as the person object already carries such information

Comment: So you mean we need 2 array lists?

Comment: Or you can use one if you want, just change the Person in the arraylist to Student. But you must supply everything at once, so all the scores too. Check my updated solution.

Comment: I have another problem. I don't know how to insert FinalGrade and Letter Grade into the Array List. I already included the method to calculate them earlier.I revised the code for the array list

Comment: That, you must create a new list, if you make sure the indexes are the same, you should be fine.

Comment: I still don't get it. There is no way to get all these in one array list?